# Javascript : создание карты ,canvas

Tags: canvas, javascript, html, css

Хочу сделать карту (которая состоит с клеток), допустим **20 на 15** клеток. Но на дисплее отображается её кусочек, например **5 на 5** клеток ("окошко"). Плюс создать 4 навигационные кнопки (вверх, вниз, влево, вправо), которые будут передвигать "окошко" по данной карте.

Я создал двумерный массив (**20 на 15**) с данными, в которых  будет информация про клетки в данной карте. Дальше создал второй массив (**5 на 5**), с данными клеток для "окошка". Создал функцию которая берет данные с первого массива и передает во второй массив. В `html` создал `25 div` (**5 на 5**) с изображениями внутри. Дальше создал функцию, которая по данным массива (тот, что для окошка) заполняет мои дивы в `html` документе.

В `onload` стоит функция заполнения (изминения) `div`, но она не сработала, поэтому на экране сумные котики. А если она заработает, то будут те изображения, которые заполнены при помощи массива (тот, что для окошка). Беда в том, что `Javascript` не выдает ошибки и не дает результата, и я не знаю в чем моя ошибка.  Код закинул в дропбокс вот [он](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qa8vg3gxw0gwib5//%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.rar).

---

Я исправил, получилось, но если перещелкнуть за границу массива,то залагает. Кому интересно  вот [код(дропбокс)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/74qqgj8uzq3i2o9//%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%822.rar?m),[код на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7VCQ/).

А чем canvas лучше? А можно ли там сделать вызов функции при нажатии на определенною область(область в самом canvas), или эту область надо делать поверх canvas  через div?

---

Canvas лучше всем)

Comment: Вы всерьез думаете что кто-то будет качать архив с кодом и пытаться в нем разобраться ? Может релевантный код сюда и на jsfiddle ?

Comment: [код](http://jsfiddle.net/CBTUh/),но там картинок нет.Как их туда загнать?

Comment: >и я незнаю в чом моя ошыбка
в том что вы очень их любите и цените.

Comment: картинки можно использовать с http://placehold.it/ но вообще, пересмотрите всю идею, то как вы собрались делать делать не стоит. почитайте про canvas,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присоединюсь к комментариям, перепишите это на canvas. По сабжу: в функции `karta_zapovnennja()` вы вызываете её саму в цикле. Получается бесконечная рекурсия, в Chrome у меня вкладка упала, в Firefox жаловалась на нехватку памяти. А ещё в функции `zahvat_karti` вы просто переносите часть массива основной карты в `karta_display`, но не отображаете изменения в документе. И ещё: ничего не имею против украинского языка, но в транслитерации названия функций и переменных на украинском выглядят убого. Учите английский и Javascript (ибо по вашему коду видно, что вы его понимаете очень слабо). Может, стоит сначала написать что-нибудь попроще (калькулятор, например), а к созданию игр вернуться когда у вас будет достаточно знаний и опыта.

Comment: Спасибо ,ваши замечания мне помогли,нашел кучу ошибок.Да вы правы, украинской язык(и русский тоже), в транслитерации названия функций и переменных выглядят убого,даже мне уши режет.